# Error when im trying to convert cpp with std includes using Emscripten

Tags: emscripten

When i try to use emcc to convert the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./emcc", line 797, in <module>
    extra_files_to_link.append(shared.Cache.get(name, create))
  File "/home/user/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 879, in get
    shutil.copyfile(creator(), cachename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/emscripten_temp_MVh5qU/libcxx/libcxx.bc'
```

I can convert any source that dont use std.
I can generate the bytecode of the example above using clang and execute with lli.

I tried in two different machines(Linux 64) and had the same error.

Can someone help me to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you tried the latest *Emscripten* with *LLVM 3.1*? I use this kind of code all the time. The only thing that is odd is you calling `emcc` instead of `em++`.

Comment: I know this question was some time ago, but to add some info, this works emcc 2.0 and clang 3.2... using "emcc test3.cpp -o test3.js -std=c++11"

Comment: @hoonto I only see emsdk version 1.22.0 at http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html and my emcc has version 1.22.0 also. Where did you get emcc 2.0?

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since the question was asked, but just to make remarks.

**It does work** on my osx 10.6.8, llvm 3.1 build from brew.

Only, the output of the 6 line code is about 113k lines and takes 4.8 MB space :) 
The output for [the tests/hello_world.cpp](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tests/hello_world.cpp) in emscripten source code is 2200 lines.